# Designing the model layer to be serializable

Tags: serialization, model, javafx

I am creating simple desktop application in javaFX 8 and I would like to be able to save the state of the model and load it next time the application starts. Therefore I am implementing the Serializable interface with all my custom model classes. First they were pure POJOs.

But in javaFX application when I want to bind the model to UI, I need to have for example `StringProperty` variables instead of simple `String`.

I realized that these property variables does not implement the interface for serialization. 
I am thinking about

- separate the clean POJO-s and than create wrappers with `ObesrvableProperty` variables for the UI
- duplicate the variables in the same class and somehow mark the property variables as transient for serialization
- adopt other/manual serialization technique

What is the best/general practice here?

Comment: Keep your model clean. Create a proxy class for each model object that implements the necessary properties and methods to support the UI.

Comment: @BobDalgleish thank you for opinion, i will look at proxy pattern, for first look it looks like a decorator pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One common approach is to design your application model in a way that is entirely independent of your user interface framework, and then implement an adaptor between the two. This allows your application to treat its UI as a plugin, which can be beneficial (both for testing and for later addition of features that may benefit from a different UI, e.g. mobile). You can also do the same thing for persistence, and any other dependencies you have.

This approach has been given various names (e.g. "clean architecture" by Robert Martin, "hexagonal architecture" by Alistair Cockburn).

The downside is, of course, increased complexity.